# How to import functionality of an already developed php/mysql system/site to drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

I have a drupal 6 site with some modules that work only on 6.x at the moment(so I can't go to 7.x for now)

I also have another site with .php files with each own mysql db tables (around 25-30) and a login system.

So what I want is, this site to be implemented on drupal and use its functionality inside drupal.
That means bypass the authorization system(login/register etc) and use drupal credentials to use each functionality.

I'm thinking of making this external site as a module (I'm new to drupal...I don't know how yet)

So is it doable? or should I consider another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to import your data from the mysql database into Drupal, you should take a look at the [Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/migrate) module.  From the project page:

> The migrate module provides a flexible framework for migrating content
>   into Drupal from other sources (e.g., when converting a web site from
>   another CMS to Drupal). Out-of-the-box, support for creating core
>   Drupal objects such as nodes, users, and comments is included - it can
>   easily be extended for migrating other kinds of content. Content is
>   imported and rolled back using Drush commands.

OR

If your current site is "web-app-like" and you want it to be a part of Drupal, you *could* turn it into a module.  In that case you may want to get a book on module development and take a look at the [Drupal Documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/develop)